# SVG Group Animation - SVG Image Slider

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm creating a masked vertical image slider using svg and I ran into a bit of a snafu.  I'm wrapping three images in a group like so:

```
<g>
<image></image>
<image></image>
<image></image>
</g>
```

And I need to animate them all at the same time.  I can't animate the y of the group.

Is there a way to combine all three images into one element and animate the element up/down?

I've included snap.svg and am using it for other animations on the site.

Comment: How about `translate` ?

Comment: animate a translate transform on the `<g>` element.